# NULL values and data truncation due to automatic data types conversion

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, doctrine-orm, sqlsrv

We are migrating from FreeTDS to Doctrine PDOSQLSrv or SQLSrv (trying both at the monent) and have encountered the problem with the data truncation of the fields that are not updated.

Our update statements look like

```
update tbl set field1 = isnull(?, field1), field2 = isnull(?, field2) where id = ?
```

We have investigated that it is caused by the data type conversion. FreeTDS runs the queries as is, so when you pass the NULL value, NULL is used. However PDOSQLSrv and SQLSrv run queries with sp_prepexec stored procedure, so it is not NULL any more, but a NULL-valued variable.

Unfortunately both libraries convert PHP nulls to char(1) (in documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/default-sql-server-data-types it is said to be varchar(1) but still it doesn't help, I can see char(1) in the Profiler), so when the field is not updated and we pass NULL, it truncates the data.

Full code example:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;

include_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$connectionOptions = array_merge(
    ['driverClass' => '\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlsrv\Driver'],
    ['host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 1433, 'dbname' => 'users', 'user' => '', 'password' => '']
);

try {
    $conn = DriverManager::getConnection($connectionOptions);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

$userId = 1;
$nick = 'test';

try {
    $result = $conn->executeUpdate(
        'UPDATE users.users SET user_nick = isnull(:nick, user_nick) WHERE user_id = :userId',
        ['nick' => $nick, 'userId' => $userId],
        ['nick' => \PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING, 'userId' => \PDO::PARAM_INT]
    );
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

So the question is how to pass null correctly?

Comment: This seems more related with doctrine I guess. There is no function named `executeUpdate` in Microsoft's `PDO_SQLSRV` drivers. Passing null directly into native drivers will be no problem but I don't know about `executeUpdate`.

Comment: @alalp Yes, the executeUpdate function is a method of Doctrine. But without Doctrine, using only PDO, one can observe a similar problem. If you pass the value `null` and do not use the` isnull` construct, then everything works correctly.

For example, code using PDO: https://gist.github.com/pr0head/aa72b8a9e7674a4aa34180f623e71793

Comment: I see that you have a discussion on github also, which makes more sense. Just for curiosity, how about using `iif(:nick is null, user_nick, null)`?

Comment: @alalp, `iif` does not work (

Comment: The developers were able to reproduce the error. https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/668#issuecomment-360591455